# How to make a Gatsby Storyblok blog index page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, storyblok

I'm trying to render a blog page to show all the Storyblok blog entries:

Here's my blog.js page

```
import React from "react"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import Blogposts from "../components/BlogPosts"
import StoryblokService from '../utils/storyblok-service'

export default class extends React.Component {
  state = {
    stories: {
    }
  }
  async getInitialStories() {
    let { data: { stories } } = await StoryblokService.get('cdn/stories?starts_with=blog')
    return stories
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    let stories = await this.getInitialStories()
    if(stories.content) this.setState({ stories })
    console.log(stories)
    setTimeout(() => StoryblokService.initEditor(this), 200)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <Blogposts stories={this.state.stories.content} />
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}
```

`console.log(stories)`

returns my blog posts [image]

Blogposts component looks like this

```
import React from 'react'
const BlogPosts = (stories) => (
    <ul>
      {stories.map((story) => (
          <li key={story._uid}>
            { story.title }
          </li>
        )
      )}
    </ul>
)
export default BlogPosts
```

But when I run it I get this error.

> TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...stories.map...')
> BlogPosts
> src/components/BlogPosts.js:5

```
2 | 
  3 | const BlogPosts = (stories) => (
  4 |
> 5 |     <ul>
  6 |       {stories.map((story) => (
  7 |           <li key={story._uid}>
  8 |             { story.title }
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `undefined` to `Blogposts` because `content` does not exist in your state at the beginning, and you set it only after your data has been fetched.

Comment: Thank you, How would I go about fixing that?

Comment: What do you have in `stories`?

Comment: [Log] Array (2) (commons.js, line 714496)
0 {name: "A New Normal", created_at: "2020-10-23T08:38:08.235Z", published_at: "2020-10-23T10:25:51.301Z", alternates: [], id: 25025557, …}
1 {name: "hello", created_at: "2020-10-19T15:47:50.907Z", published_at: "2020-10-23T08:20:26.736Z", alternates: [], id: 24427984, …}

Comment: so, seems that there is no `content` key. Just remove that condition `if(stories.content)`, and set state like this `state = {
    stories: []
  }` to array, not object

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, still not working with:

> TypeError: stories.map is not a function

Comment: Also change `const BlogPosts = (stories) => (` to `const BlogPosts = ({stories}) => (`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing stories here `<Blogposts stories={this.state.stories.content} />` but the value is fetched via async. So the template is trying to render before the value is available in `const BlogPosts = (stories) => ()`

Change `<Blogposts stories={this.state.stories.content} />` to `{this.state.stories.content && <Blogposts stories={this.state.stories.content} />}`

Comment: Thank you! I just tried this and now the page renders but doesn't show the blogposts component anywhere.